# MudBlazor - close sidebar after Navigation

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

**Problem**: the sidebar doesn't close after I navigate to another page.

**What I've tried**: adding a `OnClick=""` event to the `<MudNavLink>` to close the sidebar, however if I do that it will override the `href` (meaning it closes the sidebar, but does not navigate to another page).

```
        <MudLayout>
            <MudAppBar Elevation="3">
                <MudIconButton Style=" margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%); " Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Inherit" Edge="Edge.Start" OnClick="ToggleSidebar" />
             </MudAppBar>
            <MudDrawer Open="_sidebarOpen" Elevation="1">
                <MudNavMenu>
                    <MudNavLink Href="/index" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" Icon="@Icons.Filled.Home">Home</MudNavLink>
                    ...
                </MudNavMenu>
            </MudDrawer>
        </MudLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added `Variant="DrawerVariant.Temporary"`:

```
...
<MudDrawer @bind-Open="_sidebarOpen" Elevation="1" Variant="DrawerVariant.Temporary">
...
```